# React Hooks setState function not setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a chat application, and I have a function for selecting users you want to add to the chat. It is in the following component (I've left out the import statements and one of the functions for brevity):

```
const AddUserBox = (props) => {

  // context:
  const { friends, getFriends, user, whoToMsg } = useContext(AppContext);

  // state:
  const [friendsDisplay, setFriendsDisplay] = useState();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

  const getFriendsDisplay = async function() {
    if (!friends) await getFriends(user.username);

    if (friends) {
      let currentFriend;
      let result;
      let friendsInfo = [];

      friends.sort();

      for (let i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {

        if (friends[i].user_1 === user.username) {
          currentFriend = friends[i].user_2;
        } else {
          currentFriend = friends[i].user_1;
        }

        if (currentFriend === whoToMsg) {
          return;
        } else if (typeof whoToMsg === Array) {
          if (whoToMsg.includes(currentFriend)) return;
        }

        await fetch('/proxy/get-user-update', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({username: currentFriend})
        })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => result = data)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

        friendsInfo.push(result);
      }

      setFriendsDisplay(friends.map((friend, i) => {
        return <div 
          className="add-user-friends-button" 
          key={i}
          i={i}
          onClick={(e) => {selectUser(e, friend)}}
        >
          {friendsInfo[i].name}
        </div>
      }));
    }
  }

  const selectUser = function(e, friend) {
    let newArr = [];
    let currentFriend;

    if (friend.user_1 === user.username) {
      currentFriend = friend.user_2;
    } else {
      currentFriend = friend.user_1;
    }

    if (selected) {
      newArr = [...selected];
      if (selected.includes(currentFriend)) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
        newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(currentFriend), 1);
        setSelected(newArr);
        return;
      }
    }

    newArr.push(currentFriend);
    newArr.sort();

    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#E6FCFF";
    setSelected(newArr);
    console.log(selected);
  }

  return ( 
    <div className="add-user">
      <span>Add users to chat:</span>
      <div className="add-user-friends">
        {friendsDisplay}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => props.close()}>Close</button>
      <button onClick={() => addUsers()}>Add users</button>
    </div>
   );
}
```

The idea is that you select a user from a list and it is added to an array of selected users so that when they click the add users button the users are added to the chat.For some reason `setSelected(newArr)` does not set the state to the new array. Can anyone help me understand / fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Since setState is an async method, you don't always get the expected value when you call it right away. You can pass a callback method to your setState. If you move your console.log statement into there, you should see your expected results.

There's some information here:
https://dev.to/dance2die/accessing-react-state-right-after-setting-it-2kc8

Comment: the issue isn't just the console.log statement not showing the updated state. it seems like it actually doesn't update the state, because I can't deselect a user that's been selected, either. (```if (selected)``` always returns false)

Comment: @Chris-Capua Did you try to debug the program to investigate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing awry here is that the value of `selected` will not be updated immediately after calling `setSelected()` (see post link to thread below).

Instead of trying to access the most recent state within a callback, use `useEffect`. Setting your state with the function returned from `setState` will not immediately update your value. The state updates are batched and updated on the next render.

It may help if you think of `useEffect()` like `setState`'s second parameter (from class based components).

If you want to do an operation with the most recent state, use `useEffect()` which will be hit when the state changes:

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const decrement = () => setCount(count-1);
  const increment = () => setCount(count+1);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", count);
  }, [count]);
  console.log("render", count);
  
  return ( 
    <div className="App">
      <p>{count}</p> 
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button> 
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button> 
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[Some further info on `useEffect()`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: thank you for your thoughtful answer. I will be re-reading and checking the link you provided here shortly. I've updated the post with the function where selectUser is actually called.

Comment: I'm calling setSelected twice because one is in a conditional block and the other is not. I am trying to remove the deselected user or add the selected user appropriately.

Comment: My mistake, I overlooked the return there, although the the answer below still applies to your question. Is there something else wrong?